# Google sheet Script Error

Tags: javascript, google-forms

I have a form which submits various `scores (numbers)` and `N/A` (where the score is not applicable) , to a sheet. After each submission, I would like to change all the `N/A` entries in the most recent submission to `null` (or empty cell). That is, I would like to iterate over the most recent row (the last row) only, and do the changes.

I have a trigger to run the script below when the form is submitted, but it does not work. How do I fix this issue?

```
function mySetValues() {  

 var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses");

 var lr = targetSheet.getLastRow();
 var lc = targetSheet.getLastColumn();

 var range = targetSheet.getRange(lr,2, lr, lc)

  for(var i = 0; i < range.length; i++){

    if(range[0][i] == "N/A" ){
     range[0][i].setValue(null);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Whenever I enter N/A in the form and submit, I still see the N/A on the sheet. It does not replace N/A with null. No error occurs but nothing happens still